# Can I install another OS on Android?

Tags: installation, linux, operating-system

I have a Samsung galaxy note 3 which has root access (I think, I mean I can access and change files in /root by the help of an installed SuperSU) and I'm wondering if I can install and .ISO from a DVD, I do have a USB DVD drive and the required adapter, I'm planning on installing Ubuntu Desktop or a version of Windows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to overwrite Android with another OS or want them both?

Comment: I would like both of them just like some computers let you boot 2 OSes.

Comment: Then you need a custom kernel, that supports multiboot/multi-OS and you need a special Ubuntu build with ARM support and your hardware support. It may be hard to find but I don't think it's impossible.

Comment: Safestrap will help: http://www.androidrootz.com/2013/12/how-to-install-custom-roms-using.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a custom ROM on your Android device.

You also need a custom kernel, that supports multiboot/multi-OS and you need a special Ubuntu build with ARM and hardware support. It may be hard to find but I don't think it's impossible. reference site: [Asus Zenfone Blog](http://www.asuszenfoneblog.com/)

Comment: or you can visit this site http://www.androidcourt.com